# Dependency Issue in android

Tags: android, firebase

I have facing an error when I add my dependency which does not sync while adding authentication to my app using `firebase`

```
Manifest merger failed :
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library 
[com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0] C:\Users\Shazail Malik\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7c78a11c6b4a4456334831db0797030d\firebase-auth-19.2.0
\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
```

Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use `tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.auth"` to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Answer (score 1):

To use latest Firebase libraries, the minimum API level should be 16.

> Make sure that your app meets the following requirements:
>
> - Targets API level 16 (Jelly Bean) or later
> - Uses Gradle 4.1 or later

Check [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have your answer in the error log itself.

**Solution:**

1. Set  uses-sdk:minSdkVersion to 16 or higher in your manifest file.
2. tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.auth"

For the 2nd solution, try avoiding it as it might led to crashes for you at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Open `build.gradle(Module: app)` Under `Gradle Scripts`

Your `minSdkVersion` is 15

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
}
```

Change it to 16 like this

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion=14` than you must have to downgrade your dependency to `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5` as this allows working with `min-sdk-14`

But this is not a recommended solution. You should always have to use the latest dependencies in your project as in the latest version google aways add some new features or methods to use in the application.

For latest release please check 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

And

For firebase Auth  please check https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup